# Layout depends on "resize direction"

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, responsive-design, webkit

I'm having certain problem with my responsive layout. Lets say I have some intermediate width version (supposedly for phone landscape view), if page is loaded in this mode everything is layed out as desired/designed. And if user switches to portrait mode, portrait mode also looks good (with all responsive stuff applied correctly and all). However when switching from portrait to landscape, landscape layout gets somewhat messed up. Refreshing the page fixes everything. Same can be reproduce by simply scaling browser window down and then up. So this basically gives non-deterministic layout with regards to page width. This seems to be only present on webkit browsers. So this seems like a browser bug... Still considering the prevalence of webkit, I wonder maybe there is something that can be done about it? Anyone has encountered similar problems maybe and if so how did you solve them?

Answer (score 2):

So after digging for whole day and trying various things, like additional markup to contain layout errors, I managed to implement a solution. Namely force redraw on resize, code used to force redraw (found somewhere on the net, maybe even SO; page here is here is body element):

```
document.getElementById('page').style.display='none';
document.getElementById('page').offsetHeight;
document.getElementById('page').style.display='block';
```

As this was needed only for orientation change from mobile portrait to landscape, it was natural to assume that window orientationchange event would work, but WebKit however does not take creative layout lightly, and when forcing redraw on orientation change it instead finds third way of laying out content... So I had to bind redraw on window resize event, of course to prevent huge performance hit checks are used to only redraw page when size changed from mobile/portrait width to tablet/landscape width.